# Given the set of eigenvalues of a diagonalizable matrix, show that it satisfies an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix. $A$ has only $2$ and $4$ as its eigenvalues. Show that $A^2 = 6A − 8I$. I get stuck on this question for a while. Can anyone give me a hint for this question? Thank you.

Comment: why negative vote??

Comment: Is the order of the matrix $2\times 2$ or $ n\times n $?

Comment: If the order is $2\times 2$ there would be no point in saying "Let $A$ be an $n×n$ diagonalizable matrix. $A$ has only $2$ and $4$ as its eigenvalues." So, i strongly believe that it is not of order $2\times 2$ and i feel the question will be not so interesting if it of order $2\times e$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal it's n x n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of how to solve this problem. Fill in the details.

1): Show that any eigenvector satisfies the equation above.

2): Conclude that $A$ has an eigenbasis. (Diagonalizability)

Finally: Use linearity of $A$ and part $2$ to conclude all vectors satisfies the equation.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $A$ can be written $A=BDB^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal with all the diagonal elements equal to $2$ or $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, we can put it into diagonal form. So suppose that we have diagonalized $A$ with the invertible matrix $P$. Since $2$ and $4$ are the only eigenvalues, we can assume that the diagonal matrix is of the form
$$D = P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix}2I_k & 0 \\ 0 & 4I_{n-k}\end{pmatrix}$$
That is, we're assuming that $A$ has eigenvalue $2$ with multiplicity $k$ and eigenvalue $4$ with multiplicity $n-k$.

Using the form above, can you show that $A$ satisfies the relation $A^2 - 6A + 8I = 0$?

Alternatively, if you know about the theory of minimal polynomials, then here's an alternate (and simpler) approach. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must take on a *very specific* form. Remember that each eigenvalue appears as a root of the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

A square matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial gets linearly factored (for proof see Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze). Hence its minimal polynomial must be $(x-2)(x-4)=0$. Since matrix satisfies its minimal polynomial, we get the required expression.

Comment: you may want to re look your "A square matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial gets linearly factored"

Comment: you are right Praphulla, actually the statement is "A square matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has the form $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_k)$, where $a_i$'s are distinct scalers (Theorem 6, page 204)".